# TCP/IP client receiving and sending between various Android activities

Tags: android, android-activity, tcp, client

I need help to understand how to make a connection to a tcp client on Android with a server, the connection itself is not the problem, but rather the exchange between the activities.

I will try to explain with the attached image.

I need to start a connection to a server using TCP / IP sockets. After a search for the net I found several examples, but all using a single activity, but I need it to work as follows:

[image]

1 - Let's say in the main activity I start the connection by clicking on CONNECT.

2 - But then I need to click the ACTIVITY_A button to open another activity while keeping the connection that has already been opened in the main activity, and continue sending and receiving information in its ACTIVITY_A.

3 - Back to ACTIVITY_A, click on ACTIVITY_B doing the same process above.

I am lost between which solution to use and how to use, asynctask, thread, singleton, intent, context.

Comment: *But then I need (...) to open another activity while keeping the connection* Use Service then

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproductible piece of code showing what you have so far?

Comment: Pro tips for titles here: (a) don't add [solved] to them, use the acceptance system instead; (b) write them in ordinary flowing English, rather than adding home-made tags using dashes, bars, slashes and colons. I edited the question on this basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Service for network connectivity. Also please look at [Android Networking](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) official doc. Also there are a lot library for performing network requests (like [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice))

Answer (score 0):

I edited the previous message to inform how I solved it, it may not be ideal but it is working.

Act_Main

```
public class Act_Main extends AppCompatActivity implements Singleton.OnReceiveListener{

private Singleton sing;
String ip = "192.168.4.1";
int porta = 23;

Button btConectar, btActivityA, btActivityB;
TextView txtStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

    btConectar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btConectarID);
    btActivityA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btActivityAID);
    btActivityB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btActivityBID);
    txtStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatusID);

}

public void conectar (View view){
    sing = Singleton.getInstance(ip, porta, this);
}

public void openActivityA(View view) {
    Intent it = new Intent(Act_Main.this, Activity_A.class);
    startActivity(it);
}

public void openActivityB(View view) {
    Intent it = new Intent(Act_Main.this, Activity_B.class);
    startActivity(it);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(String dataRx) {
    // Trata a informação recebida aqui.
    txtStatus.setText(dataRx);
}
}
```

Singleton

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton instancia = null;
private static OnReceiveListener orl = null;
private boolean running;
private static Client client;

private Singleton() {
}

public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
}

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public static interface OnReceiveListener {
    public void onReceive(String dataRx);
}

public static Singleton getInstance(String _ip, int _port, OnReceiveListener listener) {
    if (instancia == null) {
        client = new Client(_ip, _port);
        client.execute();
        instancia = new Singleton();
    }
    orl = listener;
    return instancia;
}

public void sendMsg(String str) {
    client.sendMessage(str);
}


private static class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String incomingMessage;
    private boolean running;

    Client(String addr, int port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            running = true;
            // Cria um objeto PrintWriter para enviar mensagens ao servidor.
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            // Cria um objeto BufferedReader para receber mensagens do servidor.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            Log.d(TAG, "In/Out created");

            while (running) {
                incomingMessage = in.readLine();
                if (incomingMessage != null) {
                    publishProgress(incomingMessage);
                }else{
                    running = false;
                }
                incomingMessage = null;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params) {
        orl.onReceive(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
            Log.d(TAG, "Sent Message: " + message);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Activity_A

```
public class Activity_A extends AppCompatActivity implements Singleton.OnReceiveListener {

private Singleton sing;
String ip = "192.168.4.1";
int porta = 23;

Button btVoltar, btEnviar;
TextView txtRx, txtTx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

    btEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEnviarID);
    btVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btVoltarID);
    txtRx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRxID);
    txtTx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTxID);

    sing = Singleton.getInstance(ip, porta, this);

}

@Override
public void onReceive(String dataRx) {
    txtRx.setText(dataRx);
}

public void Enviar (View view){
    sing.sendMsg(txtTx.getText().toString());
}

public void Voltar(View view) {
    this.finish();
}
}
```

Activity_B

```
public class Activity_B extends AppCompatActivity implements Singleton.OnReceiveListener {

private Singleton sing;
String ip = "192.168.4.1";
int porta = 23;

Button btVoltar, btEnviar;
TextView txtRx, txtTx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    btEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEnviarID);
    btVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btVoltarID);
    txtRx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRxID);
    txtTx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTxID);

    sing = Singleton.getInstance(ip, porta, this);

}

@Override
public void onReceive(String dataRx) {
    txtRx.setText(dataRx);
}

public void Enviar (View view){
    sing.sendMsg(txtTx.getText().toString());
}

public void Voltar(View view) {
    this.finish();
}
}
```

Evidently it is not finished, but it is a beginning.

Thank you to those who have responded.